# How to get Linux to only show the last paragraph in a text file using cat?

Tags: linux, text-files

I have a school assignment, which says the following:

> **Use the `cat` command, suitably modified, to show only the last paragraph in the `textfile`**

I have already checked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308032/modifying-cat-command-to-number-paragraphs-and-display-last-paragraph-only, but it wasn't very helpful.

I am aware that you can do this *without* `cat`, but my school says I have to use the `cat` command.

Thanks! ;)

Edit: I used `cat -n  thefile | tail -n1` and it worked perfectly. Thank you Peter Bowyer!

Comment: Start by reading all of `man cat`.

Comment: What does "suitably modified" mean? Can you create an alias?

Comment: How is that a solution then? tac is not cat

Comment: @HughMungus your assignment states: "Use the cat command". As your teacher, I would say that `tac` is not `cat` and therefore you failed the assignment when you use `tac`.

Comment: Warren's always right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you had one paragraph per line.....
           `cat -n  thefile | tail -n1`